# The Windows Subsystem for Linux optional component is not enabled.というエラーが出る

Tags: windows-10, wsl

Windows10を使用しています。
[Microsoftストア](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/ubuntu-1804-lts/9n9tngvndl3q?activetab=pivot:overviewtab)で、Ubuntuをダウンロードして起動したところ、次のようなエラーが出て何も実行できませんでした。

```
Installing, this may take a few minutes...
WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x8007019e
The Windows Subsystem for Linux optional component is not enabled. Please enable it and try again.
See https://aka.ms/wslinstall for details.
Press any key to continue...
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

このエラー文について調べたところ、WSLをインストールしておかなくてはいけないとのことでした。

WSLをインストールするために、Windowsスタートメニュー→設定→アプリ→プログラムと機能→Windowsの機能の有効化または無効化という項目で、「windows Subsystem for Linux」にチェックを入れてあげる必要があるようなのですが、そもそもそれが表示されません。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

PowerShellで、 `wsl --install`などのコマンドを実行してあげた後に「windows Subsystem for Linux」を探してみたりもしたのですが、やはり現れません。

どうやったらWSLをインストールして、「windows Subsystem for Linux」にチェックを入れ、UbuntuをWindowsで起動できますか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

「Linux 用 Windows サブシステム」という名前に変わっています。
確認してみてください。
[image: Windows の機能]